# In Vuetify js how can I get select value?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to get selected value and id both from veutyfy v-select

I have tried below code

```
<div
    class="form-item"
       v-for="group in group_attributes"
       :key="group.id"
    >
    <!-- option select  -->
    <v-select
    item-text="name"
    item-value="id"
    label="Select Group"
    :items="group.items"            
    @change="select_work_type"
    >
    </v-select> 
                                
</div>
```

In select work type I am getting id, How can I get value too ?

```
select_work_type(id) {
   console.log(id)
}
```

Comment: if you need the whole object use `return-object`.

Comment: @IgorMoraru Would you please tell me where I will return object ? In item-value ?